# Very Simple .toggleClass for Div's based on HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

***This problem has been solved. Below is the original question and the finalized code. Thanks for the help Amit Joki!***

I am trying to make A tags with the class "i" on-click show/hide divs based off their ids being used as anchors. If one link is clicked the other should be switched to back to hidden.

Javascript:

```js
$(".i").on('click', function(e) {
  $("div").each(function() {
    $('div.show').hide().toggleClass("show hidden");
  });
  $($(this).attr("href")).fadeIn(1000, 'swing').toggleClass("hidden show");
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#1" class="i"> Div 1 </a>
<a href="#2" class="i"> Div 2 </a>

<div id="1" class="hidden">
  <div>Div 1</div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="hidden">
  <div>Div 2</div>
</div>
```

```
http://jsfiddle.net/krY56/180/
```

Comment: Just use `.toggle()` to show/hide then no need for CSS :ll

Comment: Using toggle breaks looping through the divs to rehide them :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is to separate the classes by a space in the same string. Not a separate argument.

Also, `attr` is a jQuery method, so you need `$(this)` rather than just `this`. Also, you need to wrap the `href` so it results in a jQuery object.

```
$( ".i" ).on('click', function(e) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggleClass("hidden show");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/krY56/168) Note, that you had set the option "wrap in head". You've to set that to "onload" or use DOM ready handler.

BTW, you can just make the following, along with transitions

```
$( ".i" ).on('click', function(e) {
    $($(this).attr("href")).toggle('fade');
});
```

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! Anyway to make the other div switch to hidden if the others clicked?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I managed to solve this because of you! :)

Comment: @KrisBowser ah! Glad to have helped you! Do mark it as answer by clicking the tick mark, if it helped :)

Comment: Perhaps you could help me figure out how to fix this with transitions now? http://jsfiddle.net/krY56/176/

Comment: That helped me figure out how to handle the transitions properly, but still wouldn't allow me to hide the other divs if the other link is clicked.

Comment: @KrisBowser you're asking too many questions in a single question. Try asking it in a different post.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem myself some months back with toggle-DIVS. Looking for something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/tu0xjdpc/1/

```
<style> .targetDiv {display: none;
           z-index: 5;
           position: absolute;
           top: 40px;
         }
</style>

<table>
<tr>

 <td class="abc">
 <button class="showSingle" target="00">x</button></td>
 <td class="abc">
 <button class="showSingle" target="01">xx</button></td>
 <td class="abc">
 <button class="showSingle" target="02">xxx</button></td>

 </tr>
 </table>
     <div id="testdiv">
<div id="div00" class="targetDiv"><img src="http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/43-small-flowers.jpg"></div>
<div id="div01" class="targetDiv"><img src="http://ps.errazib.com/img/04closeup/41live/flower.small.jpg"></div>
<div id="div02" class="targetDiv"><img src="http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/22-small-flowers.jpg"></div>


  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').slideUp();
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Your solution is very similar! However not quite what i'm looking for. Thanks for your input though!